# Transfer from multiple inputs

Tags: transactions, ether, accounts, wallet-transfer

Is there a way to send ether from several input addresses in one transaction WITHOUT the use of smart contracts? I wish that different transactions could not be linked to each other. A similar question has already been asked here, but perhaps something has changed since then.

Comment: I think there's almost nothing that you can do "WITHOUT the use of smart contracts". The only thing that I can think of is sending ether to an address. Anything else would have to involve a contract in one way or another.

Comment: Curious about why you don't want to use smart contracts.

Comment: @RobHitchensB9lab Due to lack of anonymity. I would not want to, in a situation where I need to withdraw money from several different wallet addresses, they would always pass through the same smart contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ethereum it is not possible to create a transaction where the Ether originates from multiple addresses without the use of smart contracts.

An Ethereum 'message' always has exactly 1 source address and exactly 1 destination address.

Nothing has changed in this regard.